# Why does sending a large string with PHP mail() time out?

Tags: php, email

I am attempting to send a very large string (a base64 encoded string) with PHP `mail()`.

The smallest the string will be is around 350kb, and it could go all the way up to around 2mb.

I am sending the string as a data image for the receiver to view in the HTML email, like so:

```
<img src=" . $dataImg . " />
```

When I attempt to submit the contact form with the string in a hidden field, it seems to timeout and do absolutely nothing.
Although when I send the form without the string in the hidden field, the form submits perfectly fine and I receive the email with an empty `img` tag.

I have tried testing my string within other environments to see if it renders an image correctly, and it does. So there is definitely no problem with the image.

Is there an option within `php.ini` that needs to be changed to up the limit on how much data can be sent with PHP `mail()`?

---

**EDIT:**

After pressing the `submit` button on my form, approximately 10 seconds later the following error is displayed in my console.

```
POST http://website.com/submit-quote/ 413 (Request Entity Too Large)
```

Comment: It depends on your code and the value of the string, but maybe it is breaking your message / html as you are not quoting it.

Comment: @jeroen - So something as simple as that could cause the sending of the form to turn unresponsive?

Comment: check php ini for all "max" values. Anyway, if you sending mails with pictures what source is a base64 data, outlook won't render.

Comment: @lolka_bolka - Why wouldn't it render if it was a HTML email..?

Comment: You should post your code and do `var_dump()`'s of the appropriate variables.

Comment: maybe: post_max_size.
I've read today about this. Outlook use Word to render the email, and Word has no feature like this.

Comment: I tried sending the string just by itself and not wrapped in the `img` tag, and it still didn't work.

Comment: @jeroen - The string exists and is saved correctly within the variable. The problem lies within not being able to send the email.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @lolka_bolka - Unfortunately not really. Although I checked developer tools and I am receiving a 413 error. Will do an edit on my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so check what is the `post_max_size` settings in your php.ini, try to incrase it, and restart webserver.

Comment: I am on a shared hosting plan with GoDaddy unfortunately. No restart option with their crappy services. Should I just upload my `php.ini` to the root?

Comment: As i read here, the default value is 32MB. I don't think, your post size is bigger than this.
https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1475/what-is-the-php-upload-limit-on-linux-hosting-accounts
There should be some other issue.

Comment: Odd, because the error message seems to state that I need to change some max file settings in `php.ini`.

Comment: upload_max_filesize
But please do everything in proper way, as in the goDaddy documentation. To check, is your php.ini is readed, use ini_get function.

Comment: My custom `php.ini` file is not being read. Although, the default `upload_max_filesize` is `32M` according to the `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')`

Comment: it need some time untill it's refreshing.